# Does a certain "Badecker reaction" actually exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

A book I read, mentions a certain *Badecker reaction* under coordination chemistry. It goes like this:

$$\ce{Na2[Fe (CN)5 NO] + Na2SO3 -> Na4[Fe (CN)5 (NOSO3)]}$$

I googled up the name, but I didn't get anything even *remotely* related to chemistry.

That particular book *does* have a pretty long history of typos and a couple of factual errors here and there (but I still use it because its got quite a few useful tips …)

So the question is; is there such a thing called the *Badecker reaction* (I even tried googling it up with an umlaut, *Bädecker reaction*, because, well … *Badecker* looks a little German, but then I was directed to a Wikipedia page on cadmium oxide. So what *is* the reaction’s name?

Also even if it doesn't go by that name, does the reaction actually even *exist*?

Comment: Searched for you in my mother tongue german, but had no success as well. Maybe try finding this specific reaction searching for the complex sodium nitroprusside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reaction in question is actually called the *Boedeker reaction.* How the book came from *Boedeker* to *Badeker* I do not know, but maybe there was one instance of Boedeker being written *Bödeker* which was later misparsed by a human or a robot and mistook for an a. (Replacing *oe* for *ö* is a common mistake with German names since the latter is typically used in orthography but names don’t adhere to orthography.)

The reaction is well-known and often used as a qualitative analysis for sulphite ions in solution, [much like the same nitroprusside ion can also be used to detect sulphide ions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39677). In chemical formulae, it is:

$$\ce{[Fe(CN)5(NO)]^2- + SO3^2- <=> [Fe(CN)5(NOSO3)]^4-}$$

The reaction in itself is also rather interesting since for over 100 years the structure of the addition complex was unknown. Bottomley *et al.* were finally able to obtain crystal structures of the probably structurally similar ruthenium complex $\ce{[RuCl(bpy)2(NOSO3)]}$.<sup>[1]</sup> These show that the addition product is — very much like in the sulphide case — formed by nucleophilic attack of the sulphite sulphur’s lone pair to nitrosyl nitrogen creating a nitrosylsulphite anion $\ce{O3SNO-}$. Thus, the complex formed should be named **pentacyanidonitrosylsulphito-κ*N*-ferrate(II).**

---

**Reference:**
[1]: F. Bottomley, W. V. F. Brooks, D. E. Paéz, P. S. White, M. Mukida, *J Chem. Soc., Dalton Trans.* **1983**, 2465. DOI: [10.1039/DT9830002465](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/DT9830002465).

Comment: Slightly OT: "but names don’t adhere to orthography.": this is a misconception of orthography, the orthography of names like of anything else is only a matter of definition. The definitions might show some regular behaviour, but thats essentially random.